# Logging a WCF service timeout (not to svc trace)

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, timeout

We have a self hosted WCF service which receives and processes requests from proprietary devices. during a performance test we flooded the service in order to see what happens when too many requests are received.

We found out that some connections get timed out, and its alright. our problem is that we want it to be logged in the regular log. 
We are logging to the EventLog.

How could this be done? is there some kind of a OnTimeOut event somewhere that we can hook up to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, but it seems you do know about this, here is how to activate diagnostics ([WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)).

Seems to me that you could then create your own trace listener, which write in the EventLog ? The difficulty here would be to limit the diag to just the event you are interested in, but I guess you could add your own filter in the listener if needed.